# how to connect to sql server with php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm new in sql server.i have application that use MySQL and now i want to use sql server instead of MySQL in that application. my php is:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "UNIVERSITY"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
 or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
 or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT clgname";
$query .= "FROM dbo.clg ";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
if($numRows==0){
echo "false";
}
else{
echo "true";
}

//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

i also remove the semi-colon before the

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

but i see error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\1.php on line 8
```

please help. thanks.

Comment: Did you restart your web server after enabling the mssql extension in php.ini?

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo();` in your script to see if the mssql extension is loaded.

Comment: i stop  again.and start it

Comment: how to check phpinfo() ?

Comment: Just call the function `phpinfo();` in your script, which will display info about the PHP install. Then remove the function call.

Comment: How did you get on with this? Did you get it working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP doesn't compile with mssql extension, just ask hosting provider to enable it if they support ,of if you have own server, just compile PHP with mssql extension --with-mssql=DIR where DIR is the FreeTDS install prefix. And FreeTDS should be compiled using --enable-msdblib .

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO to make this work. I use it with MSSQL and works great. Example:

```
try {
    $mssql = new PDO('mssql:host=localhost;dbname=UNIVERSITY', 'username', 'passwd');
    $sth = $mssql->prepare("SELECT * FROM STUDENTS");
    $sth->execute();
    $students_list = array();
    $students_list = $sth->fetchAll();
    $mssql = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $students_list = null;
}
```

EDIT: si-le is right, you also have to install the mssql module and add the line to php.ini for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mssql extension isn't being enabled properly...

If you are running WAMP locally, then you may have a few extra steps to complete.

I found a blog about this, and made my own here;

http://pjgcreations.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/enabling-ms-sql-extensions-in-wamp.html

The basic idea is;

1. Download ntwdblib.dll:
   http://www.pjgcreations.co.uk/BlogAttachments/ntwdblib.DLL
2. Click on the WAMP icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions then check "php_mssql"
   and "php_pdo_mssql". (Wamp will restart and give you few errors, ignore
   them)
3. Restart WAMP one more time to ensure settings are saved.
4. Finally, place ntwdblib file in the two following directories:
   "wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1" (or the PHP Directory relating to the version you are using) and "wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin" (Or the Apache Directory relating to the version you are using)
5. Restart wampserver, and you're finished!

Hope this helps!